# Using named matches from Go regex

Tags: regex, go

I'm coming from Python, so I'm probably just not looking at this the right way. I'd like to create a fairly complicated regex and be able to access the fields match by name. I can't seem to find a good example. The closest I've managed to get is this:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "regexp"
)

var myExp = regexp.MustCompile(`(?P<first>\d+)\.(\d+).(?P<second>\d+)`)

func main() {
  fmt.Printf("%+v", myExp.FindStringSubmatch("1234.5678.9"))

  match := myExp.FindStringSubmatch("1234.5678.9")
    for i, name := range myExp.SubexpNames() {
        fmt.Printf("'%s'\t %d -> %s\n", name, i, match[i])
    }
    //fmt.Printf("by name: %s %s\n", match["first"], match["second"])
}
```

The commented out line is how I would expect to access the named fields in Python. What's the equivalent way to do this in go?

Or if I need to convert the match to a map, what's the most idiomatic way in go to make and then access the map?

Comment: Since I can't add a comment below to the first proposed answer, that seems like an awful lot of code to just make a map.  I would suggest you edit the answer to show accessing a value in the map.  e.g.
    result := myExp.FindStringSubmatchMap("1234.5678.9")
 fmt.Printf("%s\n", result["second"])

Comment: There is no method named `FindStringSubmatchMap`.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can reference your named capture groups by utilizing `map` as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

var myExp = regexp.MustCompile(`(?P<first>\d+)\.(\d+).(?P<second>\d+)`)

func main() {
    match := myExp.FindStringSubmatch("1234.5678.9")
    result := make(map[string]string)
    for i, name := range myExp.SubexpNames() {
        if i != 0 && name != "" {
            result[name] = match[i]
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("by name: %s %s\n", result["first"], result["second"])
}
```

<kbd>[**GoPlay**](https://play.golang.org/p/scEnGr89tIA)</kbd>

Comment: Also want `&& name != ""` (after `i != 0`) so capture groups without names don't make it into the map.

Answer (score 18):

I don't have the reputation to comment so forgive me if this shouldn't be an 'answer', but I found the above answer helpful so I wrapped it in to a function:

```
func reSubMatchMap(r *regexp.Regexp, str string) (map[string]string) {
    match := r.FindStringSubmatch(str)
    subMatchMap := make(map[string]string)
    for i, name := range r.SubexpNames() {
        if i != 0 {
            subMatchMap[name] = match[i]
        }
    }

    return subMatchMap
}
```

Example usage on Playground:
https://play.golang.org/p/LPLND6FnTXO

Hope this is helpful to someone else. Love the ease of named capture groups in Go.

Comment: An error will be thrown if there's no match and `range r.SubexpNames()` is being iterated. Iterating over the matched content will just return nil instead, like in the answer above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53587770/422848.

Comment: not sure I understand the comment correctly, but I don't think an error will be thrown. Iterating over a nil map just doesn't enter the for loop.

Comment: EDIT: ok I think get it, the error will be on the match[i] part, not linked to the iteration itself

Answer (score 12):

The other approaches will throw an error when a match wasn't found for a 'named group'.

The following, however, creates a [`map`](https://gobyexample.com/maps) with whatever named groups were actually found:

```
func findNamedMatches(regex *regexp.Regexp, str string) map[string]string {
    match := regex.FindStringSubmatch(str)

    results := map[string]string{}
    for i, name := range match {
        results[regex.SubexpNames()[i]] = name
    }
    return results
}
```

This approach will *just* return the map with the named group matches. If there are no matches, it'll just return an empty map. I've found that's much easier to deal with than errors being thrown if a match isn't found.

Comment: "remote" must be "str" and "repoRegex" must be "regex". After that this works great, thanks!!

Comment: Pedantically, it will not return `nil` if there are no matches: it will return an empty, but non-nil, map. https://go.dev/play/p/Gxhd0Ot4nqY

Comment: Good point! Thanks. I've updated the answer to specify that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regroup` library for that https://github.com/oriser/regroup

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/oriser/regroup"
)

var myExp = regroup.MustCompile(`(?P<first>\d+)\.(\d+).(?P<second>\d+)`)

func main() {
    match, err := myExp.Groups("1234.5678.9")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("by name: %s %s\n", match["first"], match["second"])
}
```

<kbd>[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/5xGETdFWArv)</kbd>

You can also use a struct for that:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/oriser/regroup"
)

type Example struct {
    First  int `regroup:"first"`
    Second int `regroup:"second"`
}

var myExp = regroup.MustCompile(`(?P<first>\d+)\.(\d+).(?P<second>\d+)`)

func main() {
    res := &Example{}
    err := myExp.MatchToTarget("1234.5678.9", res)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("by struct: %+v\n", res)
}
```

<kbd>[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/IJyKLxlkifd)</kbd>

Comment: Best one. Fit my needs perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues with optional groups in the existing solutions. Sometimes I want them to be included in the map if they are not matched (as empty string) and sometimes not included in the map at all.

For this, I created the following method:

```
func FindNamedMatches(regex *regexp.Regexp, str string, includeNotMatchedOptional bool) map[string]string {
    match := regex.FindStringSubmatchIndex(str)
    if match == nil {
        // No matches
        return nil
    }
    subexpNames := regex.SubexpNames()
    results := map[string]string{}
    // Loop thru the subexp names (skipping the first empty one)
    for i, name := range (subexpNames)[1:] {
        startIndex := match[i*2+2]
        endIndex := match[i*2+3]
        if startIndex == -1 || endIndex == -1 {
            // No match found
            if includeNotMatchedOptional {
                // Add anyways
                results[name] = ""
            }
            continue
        }
        // Assign the correct value
        results[name] = str[startIndex:endIndex]
    }
    return results
}
```

In this method, you can pass a boolean `includeNotMatchedOptional` do define if not-matched optional groups should be in the map or not.

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/fCCf7SGMYF2